# Is there a way to make a multi-step worksheet change macro work?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building out a simple proof of concept inventory management system. To simplify the steps, I'm using excel vba's event change functionality with private subscripts on the sheets. The process flow should look like this: work order number is scanned into cell I2, triggering cell L4 to be selected. After something is entered into range L4:L13, it will then move to the next column over. Once cell O4 is changed, it will kick off another macro to update the database of entries. The problem lies in the fact that when cell I2 is changed, nothing happens.

I've tried creating multiple change event private subscripts, but that didn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WorkOrder As Range
    Dim MoveTo As Range
    Dim ChangeStatus As Range
    Dim ChangeComplete As Range


    Set WorkOrder = Range("I2")
    Set MoveTo = Range("L4:L13")
    Set ChangeStatus = Range("M4:M13")
    Set ChangeComplete = Range("O4")

    If Not Application.Intersect(WorkOrder, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

                Range("L4").Select

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(MoveTo, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

                Range("M4").Select

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(ChangeComplete, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Call Module1.EditWorkOrderStatus

    End If

Range("i2").Select


End Sub
```

I expect the macro in module1 to run and clear out all of the changed cells, but nothing is occurring. I'm receiving no errors on my code at this time.

UPDATED CODE:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WorkOrder As Range
    Dim MoveTo As Range
    Dim ChangeStatus As Range
    Dim ChangeComplete As Range


    Set WorkOrder = Range("I2")
    Set MoveTo = Range("L4:L13")
    Set ChangeStatus = Range("M4:M13")
    Set ChangeComplete = Range("O4")

    If Not Application.Intersect(WorkOrder, Target) _
           Is Nothing Then

        If WorkOrder = "" Then

            WorkOrder.Select

        Else

            Range("L4").Select

        End If

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(MoveTo, Target) Is Nothing Then

                Range("M4").Select

    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(ChangeComplete, Target) Is Nothing Then

        If ChangeComplete = "" Then

        Else

        Call Module1.EditWorkOrderStatus

        Range("o4").ClearContents
        Range("i2").Select
        End If

    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: as just a general remark, you shouldn't need Range(Target.Address) .. Target all by itself already is a range

Comment: At the end of your change event, you force it to select cell i2 again, which is why it looks like nothing is happening.  Just remove that line (or put it immediately before your `End If` line if that's where it's supposed to be).

Comment: Also, .Select is not quite enough to kick off additional / cascading change events.  Try something like Range("L4").Value = Range("L4").Value.  Be aware that this is not an ideal design.  Events kicking off events lead to weird things -- you aren't guaranteed the order that following instructions will be evaluated.

Comment: I'd steer away from having a cell update trigger an update elsewhere - most users do not expect this type of behavior: an "update" button would be more typical.

Comment: @TimWilliams I completely agree, but this is what was requested.

Comment: @tigeravatar thanks for catching the infinite loop, I've made the necessary  adjustments to my code.

Comment: Following up on what Ryan B. said:  It's NEVER a good idea to rely on an event to do anything other than respond to an action.  If you want a method (Sub) to be executed, then call the method directly when you want it to be called,  This can be as a part of your code or as the event.  What happens when you use events like this as methods, is that you confuse your code.  Now, you're doing things just to trigger an event and and not to explicitly call a method.  By calling teh method, you are keeping your code clear as to what you are doing and not confusing it with code (continued)....

Comment: (continued) that does nothing but cause an event to be triggered that has nothing to with what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I2")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!